# Mostrar parte de la imagen y visualizarla toda al dar clic

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo esta pantalla
[image: Pantalla]

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar solo un pedazo de la imagen, como el 50% de altura de la que se muestra ahora es la que quiero recortar y que cuando el usuario de clic sobre la imagen que se abra completa así como en una modal.

Estoy recién aprendiendo boostrap y lo que tengo de código es esto:

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <img src="./img/muestra.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <select>
                                <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Si le pongo un height fijo la imagen se apachurra, lo que busco es que salga recortada. Alguna idea?

Comment: Usualmente lo que se hace, es tener dos imágenes. Una normal y otra que haría la función de "thumbnail" o preview y las invocas dependiendo de lo requerido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a dar dos soluciones sencillas, una por **CSS** y otra con **JS** (jquey)

**CSS**

> La propiedad .clase:**active**, esta se activa cuando dejas el click pulsado y mientras se mantenga pulsado, una vez sueltas el click vuelve a la propiedad que posee originalmente.

```css
.col-lg-3 {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.col-lg-3:active {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="https://misanimales.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/gato-enfermo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <select>
        <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```js
$(".col-lg-3").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).css("max-height") == "100%")
    $(this).css("max-height", "50px");
  else
    $(this).css("max-height", "100%");
})
```

```css
.col-lg-3 {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <img src="https://misanimales.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/gato-enfermo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9">
  <select>
    <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

> Ya tendrías que jugar con el tamaño del contenedor o de los elementos y modificarlos a tu antojo.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas trabajar con el div que lo envuelve, por ejemplo:

```css
.col-xs-3{
  max-height: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/23256855.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select>
            <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

He cambiado los `col-lg` por `col-xs` para el ejemplo. Ahora tan solo tendrías que ponerle un listener para que al hacer clic se abra el modal, que con bootstrap lo tienes hecho ;)

Comment: Y cómo la visualizo completo al darle clic?

Comment: Como te digo, necesitas ponerle un listener y al hacer clic mostrar el modal con la imagen completa. No te puedo dar el código (ya que sería hacerte el trabajo), pero si te puedo dar las herramientas, necesitarás la [función .click de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/) y el [modal de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals). Investiga y prueba y si tienes nuevos problemas los intentaremos resolver ;)